# issue in rendering jquery datetimepicker into a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

i am trying to show jquery datetimepicker into a bootstrap modal..

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="availability_modal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                &times;
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">View availability of %SUPP_NAME%</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="availability_calender"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                Close
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the jquery i used is...

```
$(document).on("click","#open_availability",function(e){
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('#availability_calender').datetimepicker({
         formatDate: "d.m.Y", 
         inline:true,
         timepicker:false,
         highlightedDates: [
            "29.02.2016,Meeting with Pete", 
            "24.02.2016,Christmas Eve,xdsoft_highlighted_mint", 
            "25.02.2016,Christmas Day,xdsoft_highlighted_mint", 
            "26.02.2016,Thanksgiving"
         ],
         highlightedPeriods: [
            "27.04.2015,08.05.2015,Business trip", 
            "11.07.2015,31.08.2015,Summer holiday 2015,xdsoft_highlighted_mint", 
            "21.12.2015,01.01.2016,Christmas holiday 2015"
         ]
        });
    },1000);

});
```

it works fine when i am not rendering into a modal...
any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you share executable demo or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why do you want a `div` element to initialize a `datetimepicker`, but i would suggest you to change that element to a form `input` with same id.

There is a callback, when modal shows up in the browser which is `shown.bs.modal` and you can initialize the `datetimepicker` in it:

```js
jQuery('#availability_modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  jQuery('#availability_calender').datetimepicker({
    formatDate: "d.m.Y",
    inline: true,
    timepicker: false,
    highlightedDates: [
      "29.02.2016,Meeting with Pete",
      "24.02.2016,Christmas Eve,xdsoft_highlighted_mint",
      "25.02.2016,Christmas Day,xdsoft_highlighted_mint",
      "26.02.2016,Thanksgiving"
    ],
    highlightedPeriods: [
      "27.04.2015,08.05.2015,Business trip",
      "11.07.2015,31.08.2015,Summer holiday 2015,xdsoft_highlighted_mint",
      "21.12.2015,01.01.2016,Christmas holiday 2015"
    ]
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.1/jquery.datetimepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
  Date.parseDate = function(input, format) {
    return moment(input, format).toDate();
  };
  Date.prototype.dateFormat = function(format) {
    return moment(this).format(format);
  };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.1/jquery.datetimepicker.min.js"></script>



<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#availability_modal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="availability_modal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
          &times;
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">View availability of %SUPP_NAME%</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="availability_calender"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: we can use div to show it as inline calendar... however i tried your method but it didn't initialized datetimepicker... perhaps you can look at URL(http://wekue.ncryptedprojects.com/service/1)

Comment: Have you clicked this button `Run code snippet` of the answer added.

Comment: yes i checked with snippet you provided but unfortunately it is bootsrap datetime picker not jquery datetimepicker(https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker)

Comment: Why have you not informed this too in your question?

Comment: Updated you can try this mitr.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104616/discussion-between-ashish-joshi-ncrypted-and-jai).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your problem is. Does the modal show? Or is it just the datetimepicker that doesn't work?

Try adding this before the setTimeout Call

```
$('#availability_modal').modal('show');
```

Also you wont need the setTimeout call if your #availability_calender div is already in the dom

Comment: yes modal is opening but as i said.. the datetimepicker is not rendering...i also tried the way you suggested..

Answer (score 0):

> You must initialize event after `$('#availability_modal').modal('show');` as `#availability_calender` is not present in the `DOM` when you are initializing the `datetimepicker`

**Edit:** `#availability_calender` should be `input` element not `div` element.

Try this:

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('#availability_modal').modal('show');
  jQuery('#availability_calender').datetimepicker({
    formatDate: "d.m.Y",
    inline: true,
    timepicker: false,
    highlightedDates: [
      "29.02.2016,Meeting with Pete",
      "24.02.2016,Christmas Eve,xdsoft_highlighted_mint",
      "25.02.2016,Christmas Day,xdsoft_highlighted_mint",
      "26.02.2016,Thanksgiving"
    ],
    highlightedPeriods: [
      "27.04.2015,08.05.2015,Business trip",
      "11.07.2015,31.08.2015,Summer holiday 2015,xdsoft_highlighted_mint",
      "21.12.2015,01.01.2016,Christmas holiday 2015"
    ]
  });
  0
})
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="availability_modal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
          &times;
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">View availability of %SUPP_NAME%</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input id="availability_calender">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id='btn'>Open</button>
```

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/RR4hw/1267/)

Comment: surprisingly your fiddle is working like charm whereas same replica for me is not working... however thanks mate for your help...

Comment: the plugin you have used is bootstrap datetimepicker not the jquery datetimepicker(https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker) ....

Comment: @AshishJoshi-NCrypted, You did not mention any in your question..I also commented to provide a fiddle which is not provided either...